# Python Program Assistance With Loops

Tags: python

I have to write a program that takes the song of 100 bottles of beer on the wall and counts it down all the way until it gets to no more bottles left. I can get the code to work, but I am having trouble when the code hits 1. I want it to say "bottle" instead of "bottles", and when it hits zero I want it to say "no more bottles of beer on the wall". This is what I have so far:

```
def main():

    for x in range (10, 0, -1):

        print(str(x), "Bottles of beer on the wall", str(x), " bottles of beer take one down, pass it arround, " , end="")

    if x == str(1):
        print("bottle of beer on the wall," , "bottle of beer, take it down bass it around")
    if x  == 0:
        print("no more bottles of beer on the Wall",)
    else:
        print("")

main()
```

Expected results are for the output when x reaches 1 to be just "bottle" and when x reaches 0 to be "no more bottles of beer on the wall"

Comment: The indentation of your `if`/`else` checks is outside of the loop.

Comment: `x == str(1)` is never true because `x` is an int and `str(1)` is a string.

Comment: It should be `x == 1`, not `x == str(1)`, since `x` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for x in range (10, 0, -1):

    print(str(x), "Bottles of beer on the wall", str(x), " bottles of beer take one down, pass it arround, " , end="")

    if x == 1:
        print("bottle of beer on the wall," , "bottle of beer, take it down bass it around")
    elif x  == 0:
        print("no more bottles of beer on the Wall",)
    else:
        print("")
```

Answer (score -1):

The if statements should be in the loop, as the values of x in the loop can be 1 or zero:

```
for x in range (10, 0, -1):
    if x == str(1):
         print("bottle of beer on the wall," , "bottle of beer, take it down bass it around")
    if x  == 0:
        print("no more bottles of beer on the Wall",)
    else:
         print(str(x), "Bottles of beer on the wall", str(x), " bottles of beer take one down, pass it arround, " , end="")
```

Comment: Oh, so i had to have x == str(1): and the if x==0: before the actual thing. OK  I see what I did wrong. Thanks this makes a lot of sense